# Understanding Bitcoin TransactionID

Tags: transactions

How do I come to know that I have received the BTC in my wallet / the transaction is successful via the transaction ID. ? 
In Blockchain.info I used the transaction ID to search the transaction and it shows my receiving address in it. Which info graphic would indicate that the transaction is successful and the BTC is transferred to my wallet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can see the transaction on blockchain.info, it means it is part of the blockchain. If you can see your address, then you know it's the right one, i.e. that it was sent to you. Your bitcoin wallet will have the ability to see and spend it if you have that address in your wallet.

Comment: Ok. but there is no way in blockchain.info where we can confirm that the money has been successfully paid to the address. ? Is there a possible scenario where the correct address is part of the blockchain but I do not receive the BTC on the address. ?

Comment: If it says it was paid to your address on there, it was. Your question seems so self evident... Remember to accept the answer here if it satisfies your question too, don't leave your question unanswered